# Laravel PIVOT table with extra fields

Tags: php, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship, laravel-8

I've the following structure in my database.

```
users
--
id
...

products
--
id
...

licenses (pivot table with some extra informations these data are grabbed via API)
--
user_id
product_id
license_key
license_type
url
purchased_at (datetime)
supported_until (datetime)
...
```

And here are codes in my model:

```
# User has many licenses
# User has many products through licenses
User
  // User has many licenses.
  public function licenses()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(License::class);
  }
  
  // User has many products
  // Expected: products
  // Outcome: not getting
  public function products()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'licenses', 'user_id', 'product_id')
            ->using(License::class);
  }
```

Product Model.

```
# Product has many licenses
Product
  
  public function licenses()
  {
    return $this-hasMany(License::class);
  }
```

License Model

```
# License belongs to an user.
# License belongs to a product.
License

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
  
  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
  }
```

#### Route

// These class namespaces are imported and all the necessary middlewares are applied.
`Route::get('/my-products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);`

And in product controller

```
ProductController

  public function index()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    
    // This doesn't get any products. Which is what I want to use.
    $products = $user->products;
    
    // This works but I want to display more efficiently and using less DB query. 
    $licenses = $user->licenses;
    $products = [];
    foreach ($licenses as $license) {
        array_push( $products, $license->product)
    }
    
    // Get unique products of an user through licenses relation.
    $products = collect($products)->unique();
  }
```

I'm not getting any products from the licenses relation when using `$user->products`
I want to paginate the products if there are more than 5 products in a page and reduce extra layer of database queries and model loading. Please suggest some better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to perform a separate single query for products that belongs to user via license as

```
$products = Product::whereHas('licenses.user', function (Builder $query) use($user) {
                       $query->where('id', $user->id);
                     })->paginate(5);
```

or

```
$products = Product::whereHas('licenses', function (Builder $query) use($user) {
                       $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
                     })->paginate(5);
```

This way you don't have to loop through all data to extract products from lazy loaded relation and no need for unique action also

Comment: One more question: Can we get it working via ``` $user->products()``` way. ?? Just curious BTW.

Comment: @Raajen yes but this may contain duplicate products based on different licenses

Comment: @md-khalid-junaid Sorry to disturb you man. Just need another help http://prntscr.com/xyokil . I've used ->withCount(['licenses']) but instead of showing the actual number of license the user has purchased for this product, its showing the overall licenses.

Comment: Hi @Raajen It would be good if you can ask a new question with all the relevant details required to see/debug the problem

Comment: Here is the link to new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990717/laravel-pivot-table-with-extra-fields-and-withcounttable-not-working-as-expe