# Laravel PIVOT table with extra fields and withCount('table') not working as expected

Tags: eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-8

I've the following structure in my database.

```
users
--
id
...

products
--
id
...

licenses (pivot table with some extra informations these data are grabbed via API)
--
user_id
product_id
license_key
license_type
url
purchased_at (datetime)
supported_until (datetime)
...
```

And here are codes in my model:

```
# User has many licenses
# User has many products through licenses
User
  // User has many licenses.
  public function licenses()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(License::class);
  }
```

Product Model.

```
# Product has many licenses
Product
  
  public function licenses()
  {
    return $this-hasMany(License::class);
  }
```

License Model

```
# License belongs to an user.
# License belongs to a product.
License

  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
  
  public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
  }
```

#### Route

// These class namespaces are imported and all the necessary middlewares are applied.
`Route::get('/my-products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);`

And in product controller

```
ProductController

  public function index()
  {
    $user = Auth::user();
    

    
    $products = Product::whereHas('licenses', function (Builder $query) use($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    })
    ->withCount(['licenses'])   // This is returning all the licenses for this product disrespecting the user.
    ->paginate(5);
                     
  }
```

I'm not getting any products from the licenses relation when using `$user->products`
I need to display the licenses count for this product of the user.
What I'm getting is: Product B has all total 15 licenses.
What I'm getting is all the licenses count for this product. https://prnt.sc/xyokil

Comment: @m-khalid-junaid. Could you help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can introduce a closure method to filter for a specific user while loading related models as

```
$products = Product::whereHas('licenses', function (Builder $query) use($user) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
})
->withCount(['licenses' => function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
}])   
->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Simply thanks again. This is my first project in Laravel so I may be asking lots of newbie questions :)